# How do I update the ports tree on FreeBSD with portsnap?

Tags: freebsd

I'm trying to update the ports tree on FreeBSD with portsnap, but it's taking a tremendous amount of time.

These are the commands that I run every time:

```
$ portsnap fetch
$ portsnap extract
```

Are these the right commands?

Answer (score 5):

```
portsnap extract
```

should only be used for getting the ports tree for the *the first time* - afterwards, updating the ports tree is done pretty quick by

```
portsnap update
```

(after `portsnap fetch`).  So there is no real need for a download manager of some sort, as `portsnap` already fetches compressed snapshorts.  Having a look at [the man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=portsnap&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) might be advisable.